# Different ways to declare internal class variables in Python. Which is the best one?

Tags: python-3.x, class, caching, static-variables

The following code includes several different ways of declaring a static variable used by a class. Are there any functional differences between them? Are there any advantages/disadvantages for each one? Is there a better way that I don't know about?

```
# 1st way
class ApplePie:

    type = "apple"

    def __init__(self):
        print(f"I'm an {ApplePie.type} pie!")



# 2nd way
class ApplePie:

    @property
    def type(self) -> str:
        return "apple"

    def __init__(self):
        print(f"I'm an {self.type} pie!")


# 3rd way
from functools import cached_property

class ApplePie:

    @cached_property
    def type(self) -> str:
        return "apple"

    def __init__(self):
        print(f"I'm an {self.type} pie!")
```

Which method would you guys use and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example doesn't work. You can define a static variable like this:

```py
class ApplePie:

    type = "apple"

    def __init__(self):
        print(f"I'm an {ApplePie.type} pie!")
```

This is a class property (i.e. it's shared among all instances of this class), as opposed to an instance property, accessed through `self`, like in your second example. These can differ among multiple instances of a class.

Your third example is

> Useful for expensive computed properties of instances that are otherwise effectively immutable.

as described in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property).

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that I can't use self there. I've edited the code example to be correct.

Comment: @TimEstes has my explanation cleared up your confusion or is there anything else you'd like to know?

Comment: That's great! Thanks